# Debugging pandas index differences

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two identical dataframes (the only difference is the name of the columns - index and values match)

```
df1
Out[300]: 
                         C1 2018-05-17 P1 2018-05-17
Symbol YYYY MM DD Strike                            
AA     2018 05 18 29.0               0             0
                  30.0               0             0

df2
Out[301]: 
                         C 2018-05-17 P 2018-05-17
Symbol YYYY MM DD Strike                          
AA     2018 05 18 29.0              0            0
                  30.0              0            0
```

When I try to join them, pandas does not match the indexes

```
df1.join(df2,how='outer')
Out[302]: 
                       C1 2018-05-17 P1 2018-05-17 C 2018-05-17 P 2018-05-17
Symbol YYYY MM DD Strike                                                      

AA     2018 05 18 29.0               0             0          NaN          NaN
                  30.0               0             0          NaN          NaN
                  29.0             NaN           NaN            0            0
                  30.0             NaN           NaN            0            0
```

It seems that the 'Strike' is not being recognized as a match. How can I figure out the difference here?

```
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 2 entries, (AA, 2018, 05, 18, 29.0) to (AA, 2018, 05, 18, 30.0)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
C1 2018-05-17    2 non-null object
P1 2018-05-17    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 48.3+ KB

df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 2 entries, (AA, 2018, 05, 18, 29.0) to (AA, 2018, 05, 18, 30.0)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
C 2018-05-17    2 non-null object
P 2018-05-17    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 7.5+ KB
```

Update:

I've figured out that one of the Strike columns is type float

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()

df2 = df2.reset_index()

df1.dtypes
Out[346]: 
Symbol            object
YYYY              object
MM                object
DD                object
Strike           float64
C1 2018-05-17     object
P1 2018-05-17     object
dtype: object

df2.dtypes
Out[347]: 
Symbol          object
YYYY            object
MM              object
DD              object
Strike          object
C 2018-05-17    object
P 2018-05-17    object
dtype: object
```

However, even when I change the dtype to object

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()

df1.Strike = df1.Strike.astype('object')

df1.dtypes
Out[360]: 
level_0           int64
index            object
Symbol           object
YYYY             object
MM               object
DD               object
Strike           object
C1 2018-05-17    object
P1 2018-05-17    object
dtype: object
```

If I set it back into the index it changes back to float

```
df1.set_index(['Symbol','YYYY','MM','DD','Strike']).reset_index().dtypes
Out[373]: 
Symbol            object
YYYY              object
MM                object
DD                object
Strike           float64
C1 2018-05-17     object
P1 2018-05-17     object
dtype: object
```

How do I stop it from changing back?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to recreate your issue if I use a string for one set and a int for the other.  My guess is that your types are different for the Strike column:

```
tuples1 = [('AA', '2018', '05', '18', '29'), ('AA', '2018', '05', '18', '30')]
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples1, names=('Symbol', 'YYYY', 'MM', 'DD', 'Strike'))

tuples2 = [('AA', '2018', '05', '18', 29), ('AA', '2018', '05', '18', 30)]
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples2, names=('Symbol', 'YYYY', 'MM', 'DD', 'Strike'))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,2), index=index1, columns=['A','B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 2), index=index2, columns=['C', 'D'])

print(df1)
print(df2)

print(df1.join(df2, how='outer'))
```

output:

```
                                 A         B         C         D
Symbol YYYY MM DD Strike                                        
AA     2018 05 18 29      0.891830  0.670130       NaN       NaN
                  30      0.126326  0.921279       NaN       NaN
                  29           NaN       NaN  0.962292  0.822756
                  30           NaN       NaN  0.478753  0.559231
```

if you try:

```
print(index1.get_level_values(4))
print(index2.get_level_values(4))
```

Then you see they have different datatypes:

```
Index(['29', '30'], dtype='object', name='Strike')
Int64Index([29, 30], dtype='int64', name='Strike')
```

If you do

```
df1.Strike = df1.Strike.astype('object')
```

Then you get:

```
Symbol     object
YYYY       object
MM         object
DD         object
Strike    float64
C         float64
D         float64
```

Instead do

```
df1.Strike = df1.Strike.astype(str)
```

That gives:

```
Symbol     object
YYYY       object
MM         object
DD         object
Strike     object
C         float64
D         float64
```

And finally:

```
print(df1.join(df2, how='outer'))
```

Output:

```
                                 A         B         C         D
Symbol YYYY MM DD Strike                                        
AA     2018 05 18 29      0.755093  0.256132  0.291880  0.404898
                  30      0.827709  0.254511  0.849849  0.605643
```

Of course, this won't work if you end up comparing string '30' against string '30.0', so it might be better to change your string to float vs. the other way around.

Comment: Hi Troy, please see the update in my question. Your point is correct, but I was unsuccessful in changing the data type

Comment: try:  df1.Strike = df1.Strike.astype(str)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad answer but it works - not sure why

If I put the dataframe in a csv and then read it, I can set the datatypes successfully

```
df1.to_csv(r'*.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'*.csv', dtype = 'str')
df1 = df1.set_index(['Symbol','YYYY','MM','DD','Strike'])
```